# How to submit a query to Google Dialogflow using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I have the following python script that is connecting to Google Dialogflow using Flask and is using a webhook to retrieve the response from Google Dialogflow.

The limitation is that I currently only enter the query in to the Google Dialogflow frontend, with the result returned here in variable `result`

However how can I use this same script to submit the query to Google Dialogflow, instead of entering in the front end?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
import json
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response`

`enter code here # Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    res = processRequest(req)
    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    r = make_response(res)

    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r


def processRequest(req):
    result = req.get("queryResult")
    result_message = result['fulfillmentText']
    print(result_message)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return "Hello there my friend !!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')`
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered shortly after posting this that a webhook is whats known as a reverse API, and only shows results as opposed to two way interactions.